# WebSockets debugging in Chrome Devtools: how can I inspect the event: 'server closes connection'?

Tags: websocket

Here is the working websocket.
[image: Screen]
Backend developers say that server closes the connection on %some_event% but as far as I can see in the inspector it's still open.
Does 'pending' label in the inspector mean that it is open?
If server sends readyState === 3 (CLOSED) can we see the frame with smth like 'CLOSED' text and reason in frames tab?

In other words how can I inspect the event: 'server closes connection' in DevTools?

Comment: Yes, "pending" means that it's open. If you click on the left (URL/path), you'll get more info (about frames, etc). It may provide a clue why/when connections get closed.

Comment: Yep, I know: `can we see the frame with smth like 'CLOSED' text and reason in frames tab?`

Comment: I don't know, why not try?

Comment: I've tried and didn't see anything. And I don't know if it is because connection is alive or devtools just don't provide such possibility. If I close the connection on client - no, there won't be anything

Answer (score 1):

The websocket object has an onclose event you can listen to, you can get all info about it here:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CloseEvent

```
websocketObject.addEventListener("close", function(e) {
 /// Put your logic here
},false);
```

It might also be a good idea to place an event listener on errors (in the same way).

Comment: Sorry, I meant how to inspect in DevTools. Edited the question

Comment: Well, if you can you should still add it as best practice, the event object will give you more information than the ws tab in the network section of the dev tools. And if you don't have access to the sources, just write it in the console if you have access to the web socket object and you have time before it closes.